# Trying to get form values from NavigationService but getting undefined function error

Tags: forms, api, react-native, react-native-navigation, formik

I have a page named `List.js`, and a component file for List.js named `vansFilterModal.js`, Values were coming from NavigationSerice in `List.js`, but the code was too big so i created a component and moved Modal code from List.js to vansFilterModal.js and imported it in List.js, But now It's not getting the values, It's sending me this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.getParam('formData')')
```

[Click here to see error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79S1i.png)

Here is my code:

**List.js:**

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { Platform, View, ScrollView, StatusBar, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
        import NavigationService from './../../Navigation/NavigationService';
        import VansFilterModal from './../../components/vansFilterModal';
        import VansFilterList from './../../components/vansFilterList';

        class ListPage extends Component {

        static navigationOptions = {
            title: 'List Page',
        };
        render() {
                const homeScreenData = this.props.navigation.getParam('formData');
                return (
                    <View style={styles.exampleContainer}>
                        <VansFilterList />
                        <VansFilterModal />
                    </View>
                );
            }
          }

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ListPage);
```

**vansFilterModal.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { View } from 'react-native';
    import { showVansFilter, hideVansFilter } from './../../actions/instantPricesAction';
    import {  Item, Input, Text } from 'native-base';
    import Modal from "react-native-modal";
    import NavigationService from './../Navigation/NavigationService';

    class VansFilterModal extends Component {

        render() {
            const homeScreenData = this.props.navigation.getParam('formData');
            const { visibleVansFilter, hideVansFilter } = this.props;
            return (
                <View>
                    <Modal
                        isVisible={visibleVansFilter}
                        onBackdropPress={() => hideVansFilter()}
                    >
                        <View>
                           <Text> {homeScreenData.pickupLocation}</Text>
                           <Text>{homeScreenData.dropoffLocation}</Text>
                           <Item rounded>
                               <Input placeholder="Pick up location" />
                           </Item>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

**NavigationService.js**

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

const setTopLevelNavigator = (navigatorRef) => {
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params,
        })
    );
}

export default {
    navigate,
    setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Can anyone help me why its giving me the undefined error?

Comment: Please share `mapStateToProps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.props.navigation` is undefined, you have to use `withNavigation`:

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'
class YourComponent extends Component {
    // ...
}
export default withNavigation(YourComponent)
```

Comment: Ooops sorry, i am using class ListPage extends component, but i forgot to write that in wuestion. I've updated. please check again

Comment: please check again

Comment: how can i? coz it's already export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapsDispatchToProps)(Component); like this.?